# Create a module to access a 3rd party API and store the keys in the database

Tags: 7, forms, database

I am new to Drupal module development, and have searched but haven't found any tutorials or guides on how to create a module to do the following:

1. Access a 3rd party API via a form
2. Store the user API key in the database
3. Access the API key when the user uses the 3rd party API via a form
       submission

Can someone show me how or point me in the right direction for at least steps 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the storage and retrieval of the API keys in the database via the Drupal API functions:
[variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) and
[variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7).

To store the key (step 2):

```
variable_set('mymodule_api_key', $api_key);
```

To access the key (step 3):

```
$api_key = variable_get('mymodule_api_key', t('-key not set-'));
```

Where "mymodule" is the short name of your custom module.

As for a comprehensive example: There are many bridge modules in the Drupal.org repos that connects to an external service using an API and authenticates using API keys. One example of this is [Mollom](https://www.drupal.org/project/mollom).

Comment: Cheers for this! Are there any examples on how to create a module to access 3rd party APIs in Drupal? I've searched but haven't found any clear examples to learn from.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't any guides to show you how to build one from scratch? For example, I saw this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1228830